# Python Running Sum in List

Tags: python, numpy, sum, cumulative-sum

Given the following list:

```
a=[1,2,3]
```

I'd like to generate a new list where each number is the sum of it and the values before it, like this:

```
result = [1,3,6]
```

Logic:

1 has no preceding value, so it stays the same.

3 is from the first value (1) added to the value of the second number in the list (2)

6 is from the sum of 1 and 2 from the first two elements, plus the third value of 3.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you'd like a numpy solution

```
from numpy import cumsum
result = list(cumsum(a))
```

Comment: I wounder if it is that much faster then the built in Python version.

Answer (score 17):

Python 3 has [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) for exactly this purpose:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> list(accumulate(a))
[1, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about an ordinary loop?

```
a = [1,2,3]
result = []
s = 0
for item in a:
    s += item
    result.append(s)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Python has a function for this.

```
import itertools

result = list(itertools.accumlate([1, 2, 3]))
```

Python itertools solve some problems really well you should take some time and read over them.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 2):

Avinash Raj's code doesn't work correctly.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [sum(a[:(i+1)]) for i, j in enumerate(a)]
print(b)
```

Edited based on @Avinash Raj

Comment: yep, much simpler one `[sum(a[:i+1]) for i,j in enumerate(a)]`

Comment: While this has the advantage of being declarative and thus nicely readable, it notably has a worse time complexity (O(n^2)) compared to the simple iterative solution with a mutable cumulation variable (which has O(n)).

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
def running_sum(a):
  tot = 0
  for item in a:
    tot += item
    yield tot

a = [1,2,3,4]
print list(running_sum(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are about a hundred different ways to do this kind of cumulative sum. Depending on what you actually want to use the result for, a less obvious or less general-purpose solution *might* be more time- or memory-efficient—although the simple solution below is O(1) in terms of memory and O(N) in time.

The most straightforward procedural approach in virtually every imperative programming language goes something like this:

```
csum=0
result=[]
for val in a:
    csum += val
    result.append(csum)
```

The Python standard library also includes a function to do just this: [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate).

```
import itertools
result = list(itertools.accumulate(a))
```